What is an appropriate solvent to remove old headphones' "protein layer"?
My 10+ year-old headphones came with what’s called a “protein layer”. This is a supple leather-like material that's added on top of some kind of foam.
The headphones themselves still function perfectly fine, but the "protein layer" has been peeling. I continued to use them as a luxury set of headphones for garden work, where the heat and the sweat would not warrant using a nicer set.
The trouble is that said protein keeps peeling and sticking to my ears.
What is the appropriate solvent to remove old headphones' "protein layer"?

My hack is that instead of trying to remove the disintegrating material, you use a cotton shroud to cover each earphone.
Now and then, remove the shroud and shake it out, perhaps washing it too, or you can buy a pack of disposable shrouds.
You wear the headphones while doing sweaty work, so the shrouds will protect the headphones from your sweat as much as protecting your ears from the headphones.
Here's an example picture of a pair of shrouds.

